# If I run a website with guides on how to commit fraud, can I get in trouble?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, internet, fraud

If I run a website with guides on how to commit fraud can I get in trouble? If someone is arrested on the website for Grand Theft can I be charged with anything? If not what would I have to do to be charged with a crime?

Comment: What jurisdiction ?

Comment: New Jersey, is where the servers are hosted.

Comment: Your home jurisdiction may be relevant as well, if that is not New Jersey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not.

The dissemination of information is not, in general, unlawful, even if that information could be used for illegal purposes. Of course, disseminating information that is someone else's IP, is confidential or is a government secret is unlawful and in some cases criminal.

With particular reference to fraud, its already been done at least once as a book ([The Art of the Steal](https://www.amazon.com/s?search-alias=stripbooks&field-isbn=9780767906838)) and a [website](http://www.abagnale.com/publications.htm). The purpose of these is to assist people to protect against fraud rather than to perpetrate it but the information can be used both ways.

It is possible that a case could be made against you for conspiracy but that would require evidence of two way communication between you and the actual perpetrator. Accessory is even less likely and there is no issue with procurement.

Comment: I am referring to a step by step guide on how to steal from a company, I.E Step 1 Go here step 2 put in a serial number step 3 get free items.

Comment: @LongSimple If the serial number is a company secret, and you name the company in your website, I'm fairly sure the company could you try to sue you in civil court